Where does Clipchamp store temp files during screen recording
I'm trying to recover a screen recording done via Clipchamp (Windows 11). Unfortunately, the computer restarted a few seconds after I stopped the recording after Clipchamp started to process the file (about 30 minutes of recording). So I'm hoping to be able to recover from the raw data. I researched a bit, so the only usable hint was the standard profile folder:
C:\Users\user01\AppData\Local\Packages\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_yxz26nhyzhsrt

but I don't seem to find anything there (in any of the folders within the profile). Any ideas?

Is this a personal account, or business? Clipchamp docs indicate that folder is where Clipchamp stores its working files, meaning you're left with system swap/cache locations as alternative places, which would likely be lost in the reboot. Alternatively, have you used something like WizTree/TreeSize to find large and recent files on your computer?

@music2myear Thanks for the reply, although it's a company PC, I think I created a personal account (for the login), do you know if/how I can find out? I tried TreeSize and searching for recent big files, but I had no luck so far. I could just create another screen recording to see where the temp files are created but I'm afraid that I'll lose the previous temp data.

I am willing to bet the files are already gone, fwiw, but yea, in the chance they aren't, that's probably a good move.
